# Which programming language(s) is Ulteo OVD written in?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-desktop

I am doing on an academic project **Virtual Desktop Infrastructure**. I want to work with **Ulteo OVD 4.0.2** which is an open source virtual desktop software. But I am not aware in which language is Ulteo coded. Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Look inside their [git repository](http://git.ulteo.com/ovd/tree/): it is mostly C, with some Python & Java (client side ...), configured by [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system)

A general hint about [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) is to download the source code and look inside it.